zsh or bash set default variable in alias declaration
this is the desired command for context:
alias ls-last='ls -ltr | tail -n ${$1:20}' 

but this doesn't work with
zsh: bad substitution
[1]    broken pipe  ls -ltr                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

What I'm trying to do is be able to run ls-last 10 for the last 10, but if just ls-last then it would default to 20.  What is the best way to do that in this context (a single line) that would work for bash and zsh?

Start by using a function, not an alias.

If you want to know more about how you'd do this without ls in non-zsh shells, a good place to start is BashFAQ #3 -- see in particular the answers leveraging GNU find's support for emitting NUL-delimited output streams.

(...and insofar as you consider a zsh-centric answer to cover the question, maybe this shouldn't have a bash tag on it?)

Yes @CharlesDuffy agreed, I removed the bash tag

There are three problems here:

${$1:...} is an invalid parameter expansion in bash
Aliases don't take arguments; $1 is one of to current shell's positional parameter, not the "argument" to the alias.
The default-value operator is either - or :-, not : alone.

Fixing all three at once using a function:
ls-last () {
    ls -ltr | tail -n "${1:-20}"
}

However, this is fragile, as file names can contain newlines, making the assumption that the output of ls contains exactly one file name per line untrue.

As you mention zsh, you can do this with a regular glob, not the ls command:
ls-last () {
    print -l *(Om[-${1:-20},-1])
}

The glob qualifiers in (...) modify the result of the glob *:

Om sorts the results by modification date, like ls -tr.
[-x, -1] returns just the last x results.


thanks this is more than I was expecting.  Good things for understanding bash language

@OliverWilliams This isn't bash, it's zsh. They're different shells, with significantly different features and syntax, and the trickiness in the second version is entirely dependent on zsh features that bash doesn't have.

Yes correction noted, thanks
